# Friendly URL with get request form

Tags: python, django

i have this simple html form:

```
<form action="test/" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">

    <input type="text" name="first" value="" id="first">
    <input type="text" name="second" value="" id="second">
    <input type="text" name="third" value="" id="third">

    <p><input type="submit" value="Continue &rarr;"></p>
</form>
```

when user click submit button, i want to get friendly URL like this:

www.site.com/test/first/second/third

how can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where the user ends up after filling out the form and clicking "Continue" depends on what you set the `action` attribute in your `form` tag to. You've currently set it to `test/`.

If you want them to end up at `test/<first_val>/<second_val>/<third_val>/`, then you can either use some JavaScript (per pythonFoo's answer), or you can redirect in the view that `test/` points to, using [`HttpResponseRedirect`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect):

```
def test_view(request):
  return HttpResponseRedirect('/test/%s/%s/%s/' % request.POST['first'],
                                                  request.POST['second'],
                                                  request.POST['third])
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this means user ends up making 2 GET round trips, rather than 1.  Seems like there must be a better way, but I don't see it and I've been searching for an hour.

Comment: @g33kz0r How would there be a better way? Either you use a `GET` request in the form, which results in a `GET` request to `?first=foo&second=bar&third=baz`, or you use `POST` in the form, which won't include parameters in the URL, or you use JavaScript, per pythonFoo's answer below. What are you trying to do? What's wrong with the extra `GET`?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it *per se*, it just seems wasteful to my intuition.

Answer (score 2):

```
    <input type="text" name="first" value="" id="first">
    <input type="text" name="second" value="" id="second">
    <input type="text" name="third" value="" id="third">

    <p><input type="button" value="Continue &rarr;" onclick="submitFriendly();"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
function submitFriendly() {
window.location.href = window.location.href + document.getElementById('first').value + '/' + document.getElementById('second').value + '/' + document.getElementById('third').value;
}
</script>
```

This should work. It doesn't check if all inputs are filled.