# Posting with JavaScript on other page

Tags: javascript, post, get

i got this script to get Friendly URL with get request form from here...
[Friendly URL with get request form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507890/friendly-url-with-get-request-form)
here is the script

```
<form id='contactus' action='search_out.php' method='get' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
 <input type="text" name="first" value="" id="first">
    <input type="text" name="second" value="" id="second">
    <input type="text" name="third" value="" id="third">

    <p><input type="button" value="Continue &rarr;" onclick="submitFriendly();"></p>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitFriendly() {
window.location.href = window.location.href  + '/Search/' + document.getElementById('first').value + '/' + document.getElementById('second').value + '/' + document.getElementById('third').value;
}
</script>
```

i am not good in javascript ... i want to post this to new page which is search_out.php but this script post on same page ... is there a way out to post on other page ...

please help
thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the script does is take the current location. Just give it a new one.

```
window.location.href = "search_out.php/"+document.get.......
```